# NSNumberFormatter question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I'm trying to save a float like so

```
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[dosage floatValue]];
```

and read the value like so:

```
dosage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f", [prop.dosage floatValue]];
```

The Problem is that numbers like 0.11 end up being 0

I've read that I can use `NSNumberFormatter`, but the docs are not very clear on how to set it for rounding.

Comment: Did you have a look at the NSNumberFormatter documentation? There's a setRoundingBehaviour: method.

Answer (score 0):

if its already a string then y do you need to implement `stringWithFormat`?

for 2 digits floatvalue use `%.2f`
i.e.

```
dosage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", [prop.dosage floatValue]];
```

HAPPY iCODING...